# ionic 4 translateModule for two pages will cause ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: module, ionic4, translate

I am creating my app project with ionic 4.
In the past, i.e. ionic 3, I can import TranslateModule.forChild() for every page module.ts. But with ionic 4, if two pages get loading TranslateModule.forChild(), it will cause Maximum call stack size exceeded. If I delete one of them, it will works fine without stack size but just that page cannot translate any more.

Actually, my ionic version is 5.4.6.

Here are my codes:
app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  exports: [ TranslateModule ]
})
export class AppModule {}

**home.module.ts**

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomePage } from './home.page';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomePage
      }
    ]),
    TranslateModule.forChild()
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule {}


**auth.module.ts**

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AuthPage } from './auth.page';
import {TranslateModule} from '@ngx-translate/core';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    TranslateModule.forChild()
  ],
  declarations: [AuthPage]
})
export class AuthPageModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just pass the same issue and solved it, you should treat all your pages as LazyLoad just as you're actually doing in the home.module:

```
RouterModule.forChild([
    {
      path: '',
      component: HomePage
    }
]),
```

So in your auth.module the imports declaration must contain the RouterModule too:

```
RouterModule.forChild([
    {
      path: '',
      component: AuthPage
    }
])
...
```

That should do the trick and avoid the stack size exceeded. If you're using something as a SharedModule, I suggest you to add the TranslateModule in it to make it easier in your app structure:

```
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [
        ...
        TranslateModule,
    ],
    exports: [
        ...
        TranslateModule,
    ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Then in any of your next pages modules, just import the SharedModule and it's done:

```
imports: [
    ...
    SharedModule,
]
```

Hope it helps!